# Changing brightness of WMS layer in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, wms

I need to change brightness in images of a Leaflet wms layer. There is several plugins to do it like Leaflet.TileLayer.GL, Leaflet.TileLayer.Colorizr, Leaflet.TileLayer.PixelFilter, but they only works with TileLayer, not WMS layers.

Can I do this using css?

Comment: The WMS way  would be to supply your own SLD as part of the GetMap request.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, is possible to do it using CSS3 and Jquery, see jsfidle: https://jsfiddle.net/ToniBCN/t5fr48w7/

```
<style>
 .brightness{
 -webkit-filter: brightness(200%); /* Safari */
 filter: brightness(200%);
}
```

```
var ortolyr = L.tileLayer.wms("https://geoserveis.icgc.cat/icc_mapesmultibase/utm/wms/service?",{layers: 'orto',format: 'image/jpeg',crs: crs25831}).addTo(map);
$(ortolyr.getContainer()).addClass('brightness');
```